# Querying users that triggered 'app_remove' event then checking what event triggered before it

Tags: google-bigquery

I've been thinking about how to do this and have been searching for answers but to no avail. I'm actually wondering if what I want to achieve is actually possible.

What I want to do is...

1. I want to first find all users that have triggered the event 'app_remove' (thus ignoring all users that haven't triggered that event).
2. Once I find all these users, for each of those users, I want to check all events that got triggered in the past X minutes before the 'app_remove' event got triggered.

I basically want to know what the last thing a user did before they uninstalled an app.

Is it possible to do this for all users or can this only be done on a per user basis?

I didn't know where to even begin to do the group thing so I currently opted to instead try and look at one user at a time. This is where I am at currently and I got stuck after writing that incomplete IF statement:

```
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) as time_stamp, event_name, user_pseudo_id
FROM
  `mana-monsters.analytics_182655472.events_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180101' AND '20190121' AND
  user_pseudo_id = '026e1dd2cfe2344cdf2acf6dab2a123c' AND
  IF (event_name = 'app_remove')
GROUP BY
  time_stamp, event_name, user_pseudo_id
ORDER BY
  time_stamp DESC
```

I hope I gave enough information.

Thanks in advance for any help or leads as to how to approach this in theory.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `INNER JOIN` as filter could be an option here. The code should look something like this:

```
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP_MICROS(a.event_timestamp) as time_stamp, a.event_name, a.user_pseudo_id
FROM
  `mana-monsters.analytics_182655472.events_*` a INNER JOIN (SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp from `mana-monsters.analytics_182655472.events_*` where event_name = 'app_remove') b on 
  a.user_pseudo_id = b.user_pseudo_id and b.event_timestamp - a.event_timestamp < 1000 and b.event_timestamp - a.event_timestamp >= 0
ORDER BY
  user_pseudo_id, time_stamp DESC
```

I have been playing with some dummy data and it worked for me:

```
#standardSQL
WITH my_table as(
select 1454911123456789 as event_timestamp, 'app_remove' as event_name, '1' as user_pseudo_id UNION ALL
select 1454911123456788 as event_timestamp, 'app_close' as event_name, '1' as user_pseudo_id UNION ALL
select 1454911123456778 as event_timestamp, 'connection_lost' as event_name, '1' as user_pseudo_id UNION ALL
select 1457911123451231 as event_timestamp, 'app_open' as event_name, '2' as user_pseudo_id UNION ALL
select 1457911123450123 as event_timestamp, 'app_close' as event_name, '2' as user_pseudo_id UNION ALL
select 1457911123450035 as event_timestamp, 'connection_lost' as event_name, '2' as user_pseudo_id UNION ALL
select 1459911123455664 as event_timestamp, 'app_remove' as event_name, '3' as user_pseudo_id UNION ALL
select 1459911123455456 as event_timestamp, 'app_close' as event_name, '3' as user_pseudo_id UNION ALL
select 1459911123455354 as event_timestamp, 'game_lost' as event_name, '3' as user_pseudo_id)
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP_MICROS(a.event_timestamp) as time_stamp, a.event_name, a.user_pseudo_id
FROM
  my_table a INNER JOIN (SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp from my_table where event_name = 'app_remove') b on 
  a.user_pseudo_id = b.user_pseudo_id and b.event_timestamp - a.event_timestamp < 1000 and b.event_timestamp - a.event_timestamp >= 0
ORDER BY
  user_pseudo_id, time_stamp DESC
```

The dummy data would be too simple so you may have to make some modification to fit this query for your use case. This is just an example to show a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm gonna try and understand what's going on there haha especially the FROM part. There's a lot for me to take in there. But the one thing that stood out is... what do those long numbers in the beginning represent?

Comment: @CliffKamarga the long numbers are the `event_timestamp` that I created to have a similar dataset than you. They are quite random timestamps that correspond to some date in 2016.

Comment: Ah ok. I'll remember that everytime I see a set of long numbers haha

Anyway thanks for the help. I'm still working off your example so this might take a while haha.